# How to Store / Retrieve a Large Number of User Identity Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ASPNET CORE 2.0 website that is published to a web server farm. I am using Identity Role/User claims for authorization. I have a large number of claims associated with the logged in user, which is bloating the size of the application cookie. I see a few techniques for dealing with this situation, but am unsure what path to take.

- Using a custom `ClaimsTransformer`: create a custom DB store outside of the Identity Role/User claims tables and load the claims on `TransformAsync`. I'm not sure if there is a better solution that doesn't involve a DB call every round trip to the server.
- Specify a Distributed Cache Session Store when specifying the `ApplicationCookie`. I'm not sure if this will resolve the bloated cookie issue.
- Using a sticky Session to store user claims. I don't think that this works with claims authorization (`[Authorize]`)

How do I use Claims Based Identity across multiple web servers when the user has a large number of claims?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookie size is basically the strongest argument against "everything as a claim," and it's unfortunate because that model works pretty well, otherwise (I've been in your shoes). Just as you suspect, the best approach is to restrict your claims to the bare minimum and use the identity (subject id) to retrieve more detailed app-specific information from a database as needed.

If database response-time is a concern, you're basically back to stateful session data. Microsoft would likely guide you towards Redis in-memory caching. Not sure if that's an option on Amazon, I use Azure.

I tried the `ClaimsTransformer` routine, but it became a larger hassle constantly addressing "is this *really* a claim or just something we're treating as a claim?" versus just separating persistence/retrieval of real IDP claims versus internal application-level user data.

Comment: To verify that I understand your suggestion, you've gotten rid of using claims based authorization all together in favor of using a database or Redis to look up authorization as needed?

Comment: No, I use claims-based authorizations, but the only claims I persist and/or share around at the cookie level are the original basic list of claims from the identity provider (IDP). Here I'm speaking of an OAuth2 type of situation with IdentityServer4, but it applies generally to claims-based auth. Limit it to a unique identifier for the user and maybe a few useful values such as email address and phone number. Everything else is stored relationally.

Comment: I guess to put it another way, my user-store is separate from (but dependent upon) my claims-store. User identity (as "subject id") is the key value for both. For a third-party IDP (like Google or Microsoft), persist and track the IDP subject id, but generate your own internal subject id to link to your user store and other user data. That way your users can migrate to other IDPs painlessly.

Comment: What technique do you use to lookup claims in your store for authorization? Do you have custom authorization attributes that perform the work as opposed to injecting the claims using a ClaimsTransformer?

Comment: I'm using IdentityServer4, so as far as claims go, I just register the store as a service with the persistence interface defined by IS4, and IS4 uses it. On the client side, the claims get loaded up automatically through ASP.NET Core's OIDC middleware as long as I use the built-in sign-in/sign-out methods, so I just check `User` to figure out if they're authenticated and what the claims are and so on. It's pretty automatic that way.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into migrating that direction. Any helpful links that could give me more info on your preferred implementation?

Comment: I blogged about using IdentityServer4 without Entity Framework [here](https://mcguirev10.com/2018/01/02/identityserver4-without-entity-framework.html). It's intentionally simple (for example, ad-hoc SQL in code) and only trivially related to my production systems (for example, there is a lot more code to write to manage multiple providers etc), but it's complete and it works.